# How to register Native Classes or Functions in PySpark?

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I've been doing PySpark lately, and I have one question that caught my mind after reading this blog post

https://mungingdata.com/apache-spark/registerfunction-injectfunction/

Is there a way to do this in Python? For instance, I'd like to have a class such as

```
MyClass(??):
    """
    A PySpark Class
    """

    return self.read.load(path/to/file)

<somecode here to register it>
```

and then, from my spark session, I'd like to do something like

`myDf = spark.MyClass()`

is this possible in PySpark?

The main motivation is to have a wrapper around PySpark somehow to provide specific augmented functionalities.

Comment: what is blocking you currently ? have you tried something and it's failling ? or you're just asking for general advices ?

Answer (score 0):

You are working in python, so I do not really understand what is blocking you.

Here is a code samplet for doing somehow what you want to do :

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


class Singleton(type):
    _instances = {}

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]


class Spark(metaclass=Singleton):
    def __init__(self):
        self._spark = (
            SparkSession.builder.master("yarn").appName(app_name).getOrCreate()
        )

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self._spark, attr)

    # Add any other method you'd like
```